# appengine: convert ndb model to go lang struct

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go

I've got a python module and a go module on app engine. The go module is fairly simple and just provides a readonly search interface to the datastore which is populated by the python module.

How do I convert the following ndb model into a go struct:

```
class Course(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    neat_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    country = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Country, required=True)
    university = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=University, required=True)
    faculty = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Faculty, required=True)
    department = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Department, required=True)
    stage = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Stage, required=True)

    legacy_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    course_title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
    course_description = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    course_link = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)

    #0-5 or None or not has attribute.
    course_rating_ = ndb.FloatProperty()
    course_review_count_ = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

To start with I'll have:

```
type Course struct {
    Name string `datastore:"name"`
    NeatName `datastore:"neat_name"`
    ...
}
```

For the `ndb.KeyProperty` properties - Do I just use a `string` in my `struct`? & I'll have to parse that string - is that straight forward?

Also can I just ignore the `required=True` & `indexed=False` options? Obviously since i'm not doing any writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Properties_and_value_types , `String` (a short string of up to 500 characters, indexed by default) maps to Go `string`; `Text` (a long string up to 1MB, not indexed) also to Go `string` but always with `noindex`; for datastore `Key` there is `*datastore.Key`, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Key ; for `Integer`, `int64`; for `Float`, `float64` (you could use shorter ints and floats but the datastore uses 64 bits for each anyway so you might as well:-).

> Also can I just ignore the `required=True` & `indexed=False` options?

Yes for `required`, but I believe that, using https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference , you do have to use option `noindex` for `Text` because it's necessary to indicate strings that can be longer than 512 (unicode) characters.

Not sure which versions of `go` and its `datastore` package enforce this constraint, but even if the present one doesn't it's safer to respect it anyway -- or else your app might break with a simple Go version upgrade!-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code - it's working in production & locally too:

```
type Course struct {
    Name              string         `datastore:"name"`
    NeatName          string         `datastore:"neat_name"`
    Country           *datastore.Key `datastore:"country"`
    University        *datastore.Key `datastore:"university"`
    Faculty           *datastore.Key `datastore:"faculty"`
    Department        *datastore.Key `datastore:"department"`
    Stage             *datastore.Key `datastore:"stage"`
    LegacyId          string         `datastore:"legacy_id"`
    CourseTitle       string         `datastore:"course_title,noindex"`
    CourseDescription string         `datastore:"course_description"`
    CourseLink        string         `datastore:"course_link,noindex"`
    CourseRating      float64        `datastore:"course_rating_"`
    CourseReviewCount int64          `datastore:"course_review_count_"`
}
```

and

```
func (ttt *EdSearchApi) Search(r *http.Request,
    req *SearchQuery, resp *SearchResults) error {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Course").Limit(1)
    var courses []Course
    _, err := q.GetAll(c, &courses)
    c.Infof("err %v", err)
    c.Infof("courses 0: %v", courses[0])
    c.Infof("!!!")
    return nil
}
```